# rspec mocking "undefined method `stub_model' for #<Class:0x007ff9c339bd80> (NoMethodError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec-rails

I'm using Rails 3.1 and I wanted to add some stubs and mocks to my specs but I get a NoMethodError:

```
undefined method `stub_model' for #<Class:0x007ff9c339bd80> (NoMethodError)
```

Here is an excerpt of my GemFile:

```
gem 'rspec'
gem 'rspec-rails'
```

I ran bundle install and rails g rspec:install

And here is the code that tries to create a stub_model

```
  0     @flight = stub_model(Flight)
  1     Flight.stub! (:all).and_return([@flight])
```

And here is spec_helper.rb:

```
  0 # This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
  1 ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  2 require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  3 require 'rspec/rails'
  4 
  5 # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
  6 # in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
  7 Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
  8   
  9 RSpec.configure do |config|
 10   # == Mock Framework
 11   #
 12   # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
 13   #
 14   # config.mock_with :mocha
 15   # config.mock_with :flexmock
 16   # config.mock_with :rr
 17   config.mock_with :rspec
 18 
 19   # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
 20   config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
 21     
 22   # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
 23   # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
 24   # instead of true.
 25   config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
 26 end
```

I'm calling "rspec ./spec" and "bundle exec rspec ./spec"  (tried both, no difference)

Everything I'm doing seems to be textbook (in fact, I'm following The Rails 3 Way).

What am I missing?

Comment: Where is the stub_model called from? A controller spec? A view spec? A model spec?

Comment: Um... it just decided to start working.  I set up a new project to test the behavior out in, and it worked fine in that project.  Then I tried the original project again and that worked fine.  Weird.

Comment: A few more context lines around your failing code would probably have made the error obvious to someone sooner :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comment in original question.  Like a bad knot in my neck, it seems to have worked itself out.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are that your original code was being run outside of a spec example. This will give the error you describe:

```
class Foo; end
describe Foo do
  @foo = stub_model(Foo)
  Foo.stub!(:all).and_return([@foo])
end
```

but this will work:

```
class Foo; end
describe Foo do
  before do
    @foo = stub_model(Foo)
    Foo.stub!(:all).and_return([@foo])
  end
end
```